# How to implement Dark Mode in react native application?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build an application in react native and want to implement the dark mode in that application. But not able to understand how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself, however, after a quick search on Google, I've come up with this few links you might find useful:

- https://medium.com/@eroticbroccoli/implementing-dark-mode-on-react-native-2bfeb624fa3d
- https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/switching-off-the-lights-adding-dark-mode-to-your-react-app-with-context-and-hooks-f41da6e07269
- https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/aor0pp/provide_darklight_theme_switcher_for_app/